# eval a list into a let on clojure

Tags: binding, clojure, eval, let

My problem is the next, i try to evaluate a list with some vars using a let to asign values to this vars

if i do `(def a (list * 'x 'y))` and `(let [x 3 y 3] (eval a))` I have a 
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: x in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:6)

but if I run
`(def x 4) (def y 4)` and `(eval a)` i have a 16,  anyway if I run  again `(let [x 3 y 3] (eval a))` again I have 16,

exist a method to binding the x and y correctly and eval the list?

ty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could also `eval` the `let` expression, See if this is what you need:

```
(eval '(let [x 3 y 3] (* x y)))
```

**EDIT :**

According to the comments, this will work for your case:

```
(def a (list (list * 'x 'y)))
(eval (concat '(let [x 3 y 3]) a))
```

Even better, use quasiquoting:

```
(def a (list * 'x 'y))
(eval `(let ~'[x 3 y 3] ~a))
```

Answer (score 5):

`let` defines lexically scoped bindings that are not accessible from the body of the eval function.  This is no different than any other function.  However, the bindings created with `def` are accessible because they are namespace global.  All functions have access to namespace global variables, as long as they are public.

Answer (score 3):

```
(def ^:dynamic x 4) (def ^:dynamic y 4)
user=> (binding [x 3 y 3] (eval a))
9
user=> (eval a)
16
```