# Clojure DRY pattern for hash-map?

Tags: clojure, dry

I do a lot of computation in `let` blocks, returning hash-maps containing the data. The following is a not-so-minimal example:

```
(def ground-truth
(let [n              201
      t1             2.0
      linspace       (fn [a b n] (let [d (/ (- b a) (dec n))]
                                   (map (fn [x] (+ a (* x d))) (range n))))
      times          (vec (linspace 0.0, t1, n))
      wavelength     1
      wavespeed      1
      f              (* (/ wavespeed wavelength) 2 Math/PI)
      dt             (- (get times 1) (get times 0))
      amplitude      5.0
      ground-level   10.0
      h-true         (mapv #(+ ground-level 
                               (* amplitude (Math/sin (* f %))))
                           times)
      h-dot-true     (mapv #(* amplitude f (Math/cos (* f %)))
                           times)
      baro-bias-true -3.777]
    {:n n, :times times, :f f, :dt dt, :h-true h-true,
     :h-dot-true h-dot-true, :baro-bias-true baro-bias-true}))
```

What I want to do is get rid of the repetition in the final expression. It's not such a big problem for this little example, but I have some that are much longer and more elaborate and the repetition makes modifying the expression tedious and error-prone.

I tried this macro:

```
(defmacro hashup [name-list]
`(into {}
        (map vector
             (mapv keyword ~name-list)
             (mapv eval    ~name-list))))
```

which works only if `eval` works, which works on `vars`:

```
(def foo 41) (def bar 42)
(hashup '[foo bar])
```

> {:foo 41, :bar 42}

but not on `let` blocks:

```
(let [a 1, b (inc a)] (hashup '[a b]))
```

> CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: a in this context, compiling:(null:1:1) 
>                Util.java:   221 clojure.lang.Util/runtimeException
>                core.clj:  3105 clojure.core$eval/invokeStatic

as expected after reviewing the following SO questions, amongst many others: [Variable scope + eval in Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221716/variable-scope-eval-in-clojure), [eval a list into a let on clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662489/eval-a-list-into-a-let-on-clojure/8662740#8662740)

One might say "well, you can either have repetition outside your `let` blocks by `def`fing your variables in namespaces and then using something like `hashup`, or you can have your repetition at the bottom of your `let` blocks and forget about macro magic. But there is no way to *Don't Repeat Yourself* in this exact use case.

Did I miss a good way to DRY out this kind of code?

Comment: Not an answer, but you might want to have a look at `fnk` from https://github.com/plumatic/plumbing

Comment: Just a little advice in addition to the fine answer by Wout Neirynck: the problem with your own attempt at a macro is that you're treating it too much like a regular function, i.e. you're trying to create the vector directly. A macro should not try to create the final result, but rather create an expression that will create the final result when it gets evaluated. Since you're creating an expression that will then get evaluated, you don't need to use `eval` explicitly.

Comment: @Rörd from your explanation, I think I now have a much better understanding of when evaluation happens with macros: we get a rewrite of code first with no evaluation, then evaluation later at run time. That's consistent with Wout's answer below, in which `vars` is never evaluated. The reflex of prefixing every macro with a backtick to suspend evaluation induces a distraction: the evaluation it's suspending is rewrite-time evaluation, which should not be conflated with run-time evaluation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
(defmacro ->hash [& vars]
  (list `zipmap
    (mapv keyword vars)
    (vec vars)))
```

Then:

```
(->hash a b c) => {:a a :b b :c c}
```

And it also works inside `let` blocks.

Comment: Definitely use s backquote here rather than an ordinary quote. `'zipmap` will fail to work if the caller's namespace does not resolve `zipmap` to `clojure.core/zipmap`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do what [flatland.useful.map/keyed](https://github.com/amalloy/useful/blob/96f6650/src/flatland/useful/map.clj#L6) does: generate the map structure at compile time, instead of making the caller generate a vector of keys, and a vector of values, and then call zipmap on them. A simpler version of the same thing, if you don't care about being able to build maps like this keyed by string or by symbol, would be:

```
(defmacro keyed [ks]
  (into {}
    (for [k ks]
      [(keyword k) k])))

(let [x 1, y 2]
  (keyed [x y]))

; {:x 1, :y 2}
```

Note that useful chooses to wrap things in an "unnecessary" vector here for symmetry with the `{:keys [x y]}` destructuring form, and as mentioned also provides `:strs` and `:syms` analogues.

Answer (score 1):

Try that one:

```
(defmacro letm
  [bindings]
  `(let* ~(destructure bindings)
     (merge ~@(map #(hash-map (keyword %) %) (take-nth 2 bindings)))))

(letm [a 1
       b (+ 1 2)
       c (println "As")
       d (+ b 2)
       e 'selam])

=> As
=> {:a 1, :b 3, :c nil, :d 5, :e selam}
```